# How to get custom attributes back from AWS Cognito & OIDC when using AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

We're developing a website with AWS Amplify that uses Cognito to handle the authentication. I've configured the user pool in Cognito to use Keycloak as the OIDC IDP. The basics of logging in and out are all working as desired.

I now want to get more information back from Keycloak into the Amplify app. If I use https://openidconnect.net/ as a test point for authenticating to Keycloak as if it was Cognito, I can decode the JWT in https://jwt.io and see the additional information I'm after.

In Cognito, in General Settings > Attributes, I've added a custom attribute "groups":

[image: custom attribute screenshot]

In General settings > App clients, I've marked that attribute as readable:

[image: app attribute screenshot]

Under Federation > Attribute mapping, I've mapped the OIDC attribute to the User pool attribute:

[image: federation attribute mapping]

but, when I authenticate in the web application and dump the payloads for the ID and access tokens, I cannot see the "custom:groups" attribute.

What am I missing or misunderstanding here?

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MikeCrowe no. In the end, we decided that group management needed to be a feature of the app and therefore managed within Cognito, rather than allowing the IDP to pass through groups that may not be relevant or may override our app's groups.